# How to get from $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$ to $1 +\frac{n+1-n-2}{(n+2)!}$?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, induction

I want to understand the proof of induction for

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

[image]

What I don't understand is how we get from:

$$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\tag{1}$$

to this step:

$$1 +\frac{n+1-n-2}{(n+2)!}\tag{2}$$

I believe we have to get to the common denominator using:

$$1 + \frac{(n+2)!}{(n+1)! (n+2)!} + \frac{(n+1)(n+1)!}{(n+2)!(n+1)!}$$

but this just leads to

$$1 + \frac{(n+2)! + (n+1)(n+1)!}{(n+2)! (n+1)!}$$

How does one continue from here?

**EDIT:**

Can we also do the following?

$$1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}  \\ 
= 1 + \frac{-(n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} + \frac{(n+1)(n+1)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} \\ = 1 + \frac{-(n+2)!+(n+1)^2n!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} \\ 
= 1 + \frac{n!(-n+1)(n+2)+(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} \\
= 1 + \frac{-(n+1)(n+2)+(n+1)^2}{(n+1)(n+2)!} \\
= 1 + \frac{(n+1)(-(n+2)+(n+1))}{(n+1)(n+2)!} \\
= 1 + \frac{-n-2+n+1}{(n+2)!} \\
= 1 + \frac{-1}{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator of $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ by (n+2) to get $\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}$.

Comment: To get the common denominator, you only need to multiply the first fraction, top and bottom, by $n+2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to notice is that $(n+2)! = (n+2)\times(n+1)!$, so
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
can be rewritten as
$$\frac{(n+2)\times1}{(n+2)\times(n+1)!}=\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}.$$

The result follows by grouping the two fractions with $(n+2)!$ as their denominator.

Comment: What is this rule called? That $(n+2)! = (n+2) \cdot (n+1)!$

Comment: It's the definition of factorial

Comment: @user10930711 it is a (recursive) definition of the factorial: $(n+2)!=(n+2)\times(n+1)\times n\times\ldots=(n+2)\times(n+1)!$.

Comment: You need to be careful when grouping the two fractions: the minus sign only applies to the first fraction in (1). You would first negate the fraction that you obtain as shown in my answer, and then perform the grouping, giving you the expected $\dfrac{-(n+2)+(n+1)}{(n+2)!}$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my edited post and see if I can use this approach too?

Comment: Yes, this is also a valid (albeit less direct) way to get to the result!

Answer (score 1):

$$1+\frac{n+1-n-2}{(n+2)!}=1+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}-\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: I don’t think this is it. The OP asked an explanation of how to go from (1) to (2); you have shown how to go from (2) to (1).

Comment: Yes, but fortunately equalities are symmetric. Read it right to left and that's the answer

Comment: *reads from right to left*—looks good

Answer (score 1):

$$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}= 1+\frac{n+1-n-2}{(n+2)!}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you check my edited post and see if I can use this approach too?

Comment: For the first line in your edited post, the second term seems not same as the OP?@user10930711

Comment: Missed a faculty there, sorry

Comment: Yes, you can, but on the 4-th line, you need take that $n!$ out, or put a parenthesis there @user10930711

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!